# Bug: Redirect to canonical javascript issue

Tags: javascript, html, canonical-link

Trying to achieve a Redirect to the original "canonical link" using  javascript. **I have encountered a weird bug!**

The script works in this URL ending:

/index.php/topic,000.0/ **wap2.html**

But **FAILS** to work with this one:

/index.php/topic,000.0.html **?wap2**

What's weird is I can see the script in the HTML source... it SHOULD be working but it's NOT! Any ideas or some guidence to get thy old brain juices flowing would be great.

Help?

```js
if (document.querySelector("link[rel='canonical']")) {

 // Get current URL
 var url = document.URL;

 // If query string, get it and append to current URL
 if (location.search) {
  var query = location.search;
 } else {
  var query = '';
 }

 // Get canonical URL
 var canonical = document.querySelector("link[rel='canonical']").href;

 if (url !== canonical + query) {
  window.location.replace(canonical + query);
 }

}
```

Comment: What is the failure? Do you get an exception?

Comment: The javascript does not execute with "?wap2" url ending. I don't understand why. I can even see the script in the HTML source code. :S

Comment: How do you include the script- a 'script' tag? an external js file? do you get any js error on the console? try to debug your code or maybe use console.log() in your code to see where you get to. It's impossible to guess what is the problem without a working example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I just use the <script> tags. Thanks for the advise, I will look it over.

Comment: I found the problem, if the visitor visits the page, they are redirected to the "canonical link". The problem is, if they already have a cached version of the URL ending with **"?wap2"** and they hit "refresh", the script does not execute. Any help?